# IE6: How to get inline base64 images to work with IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, image, conditional-statements, base64

How do I get IE6 to display inline base64 encoded images?

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,....." />
```

This works in Firefox/Chrome/Safari but not IE6.

Comment: Just curious: why would you (or anyone) want to do this? Wouldn't a cacheable image be preferred for all browsers? Seems fine to me in an external CSS file, but not in HTML.

Comment: Cacheable as in: any image that is downloaded as usual and can then be cached by a browser. Or is this used in some single-file, non-hosted HTML?

Comment: Inline reduces HTTP requests.

Comment: But it makes the request larger, assuming that the HTML will be refreshed more often than the image, and the image may also be used on other pages?

Comment: @Jacob: Inline might reduce the number of HTTP requests, but 1) you have to transfer more data because the encoding makes the binary image data larger, 2) modern browsers can load the page faster if the image is a separate resource that can be downloaded in parallel and 3) caching might not work as good, especially if your page is dynamically generated.

Comment: Arjan van Bentem, sometimes an application needs to generate an image on the fly. In such a case, it is sometimes easier to inline the image rather than creating a file and sending a link.

Comment: @divo, the file size is the same when you use mod_deflat which gzips the image content.

Comment: gzips the base64 encoding that is

Comment: If you're worried about http request you may want to look into sprites for your images. Then you would only have to do two http requests for the page and all the images.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

This may not be helpful for your situation, if for instance you are generating html and a single image.

Comment: @bmp, true, that is good scenario. Any other use in HTML makes me doubt though.

Answer (score 13):

My solution run smoothly on IE6. It may help you!

```
<!--
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_data-uri"
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#pic {
width:670px;height:710px;
background-image: expression("url(mhtml:" + window.location + "!locoloco)");
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<div id="pic" ></div>
<div id=test style="display: none;">

--=_data-uri
Content-Location:locoloco
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8  /w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
--=_data-uri--

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here? It looks interesting, but for example... !locoloco?

Comment: @Chris This makes use of multi-part HTML (see my answer below) — a scarcely-implemented technique for describing multiple resources in a single HTML file. Since the file will have a single URI, the various parts are given 'Content-Location' headers which can be referenced with a preceding `!` then appended to the location (just as `#` specifies a given DOM node location within an HTML document).

Answer (score 6):

Install Google's Chrome Frame?

Seriously, you can't.  IE6 does not have support for base64 inline images.

Comment: Can I do conditional statement so that IE6 links to the actual file but for all else, it displays the base64?

Comment: You would have to dynamically set the src using javascript, which IMO is more hassle than it's worth.  Loading images from the server isn't a bad thing; it means users can cache them for multiple page loads.  Why are you trying to make them inline?

Comment: The sad part about Chrome Frame is that corporations aren't going to start picking it - and they're the ones still using IE6. As such, it's relatively silly and sad all at the same time. It's an interesting idea, but wasted on the developers and not the end-users.

Comment: Conditional comments should do the job, but why include the base64 image then? It will be larger than the original image and browsers can load a separate image file faster. If you want a single file you might want to look at the MHTML (.mht) file format which works with IE 5 and above. Support in other browsers is poor though. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML.

Comment: Inline images reduce HTTP GET requests. This is great for lots of small pictures.

Comment: For lots of small images I'd use sprites instead.

Comment: If you really have *many* pictures you could combine them in a larger image and use CSS clip to only display the part you want: <div style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; clip:rect(0px, 130px, 130px, 0px);">
<img src="image.png" width="208" height="181" alt="bla" /></div>

Comment: I also like to play with inline pngs but in the end sprites are the way to go!

Comment: See below answers, especially Dean Edwards's "sexy" solution - it's small and does the job - tested and verified in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: -1 because working solutions have been posted, and the proposed workaround isn't a solution to the specific technical problem described.

Answer (score 4):

IE6 needs an expression to correctly interpret base 64 encoded images. Dean Edwards describes the solution here: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-sexy/

Note: this is a very ugly hack. In the first place we were putting image code in our CSS; with this solution you need to either put presentational data in Javascript, or behavioural data in your CSS. Nasty but necessary.

Answer (score 2):

base64 images are showing up in IE6 and IE7... in the last i found a simple solution when you are using a encoded images in css.

**"write two attributes in a same class. Use css browser specific hacks"**

I am going to explain it below.

```
   <div class="myClass">    </div>
    <style>
            .myClass{
                    background=url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAHCAYAAADam2dgAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAySURBVHjaYlSdd/4/AwQwQml0PgMTHsn/yIoYCCmEKcKrEFkRTrcxEVIAs46g7wACDACraA+g90OOjwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D'); 
    /* Above property will work for all browsers*/

                    *background=url('give real path_to_image'); 
/* This will work only for ie6 and ie7 */
                    }
        </style>
```

Comment: I think this is a simple way to overcome problem of IE6 and IE7. I welcome, If anyone have any other better solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't for a corporate setting, I'd say just drop IE6 support all together, and have people install [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) if they insist on using such an outdated browser.

Comment: Can I do conditional statement so that IE6 links to the actual file but for all else, it displays the base64?

Comment: Depends, are you using a scripting language like PHP?

Comment: How would PHP help? This would have to be performed on the client side. No,just HTML

Comment: If you were to use PHP, or any other web language, you could check the user's agent string and make a decision based on that.

Comment: @darkassassin93: Jacob is referring to conditional HTML comments, an IE-specific feature to support browser-specific behavior within HTML. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 in CSS, at least.
Please take a look: http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/

Perhaps more research could possible help using mhtml:// for inline images, too.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a quick fix to make Base64 images showing up in IE6 again:

[Base64 image fix for Internet Explorer](http://ehealth-aussie.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/base64-image-fix-for-internet-explorer.html)

*Sorry for the broken link, now comes the correct one!

I think this is a non-intrusive way to make things working again. It actually repair the images after you have those broken images (broken icon) already displayed on IE.

Answer (score -1):

**ORGINAL**

I do not believe IE6 supports in-line data for the `<img/>` tag. However, you might want to try another format like GIF or JPG.

**EDIT**
Given the fact that it took IE forever to accurately support PNG (still debatable) one could easily deduce that PNG might not be supported as an in-line data format for `<img/>` tags. With that said, goto `**ORIGINAL**`

Comment: If IE6 does not support in-line data, would it matter what the format is?

Comment: Maybe mimetnet is thinking that the problem is lack of *PNG* support, in which case GIF or JPG might work.

Comment: IE6 supports PNG (but no alpha transparency, although there seem to be workarounds, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714)

Comment: IE has supported PNG since some 4.x version. (Transparent PNG has been troublesome though.)

Comment: IE6 DOES in fact support PNG. It just doesn't support 32bit alpha channel.