# Base64 Image not showing up in IE6

Tags: html, image, base64, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to render an image in `IE6` from a `base64` encoded string. As per the resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575333/ie6-how-to-get-inline-base64-images-to-work-with-ie6) and [here](http://venodesigns.net/2010/06/17/you-got-your-base64-in-my-css/), I am trying out this following code (the image is just the `base64` encoding of my profile pic here... :), obtained from [this site](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create))

```
<!--
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_data-uri"
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#pic {
width:670px;height:710px;
background-image: expression("url(mhtml:" + window.location + "!locoloco)");
}
</style>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() { alert(window.location); }
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div>Foo</div>
<div id="pic" ></div>
<div id=test style="display: none;">

--=_data-uri
Content-Location:locoloco
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApkZXNjAAAA/AAAAF5jcHJ0AAABXAAAAAt3dHB0AAABaAAAABRia3B0AAABfAAAABRyWFlaAAABkAAAABRnWFlaAAABpAAAABRiWFlaAAABuAAAABRyVFJDAAABzAAAAEBnVFJDAAABzAAAAEBiVFJDAAABzAAAAEBkZXNjAAAAAAAAAANjMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB0ZXh0AAAAAEZCAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLVhZWiAAAAAAAAADFgAAAzMAAAKkWFlaIAAAAAAAAG+iAAA49QAAA5BYWVogAAAAAAAAYpkAALeFAAAY2lhZWiAAAAAAAAAkoAAAD4QAALbPY3VydgAAAAAAAAAaAAAAywHJA2MFkghrC/YQPxVRGzQh8SmQMhg7kkYFUXdd7WtwegWJsZp8rGm/fdPD6TD////bAEMACAYGBwYFCAcHBwkJCAoMFA0MCwsMGRITDxQdGh8eHRocHCAkLicgIiwjHBwoNyksMDE0NDQfJzk9ODI8LjM0Mv/bAEMBCQkJDAsMGA0NGDIhHCEyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMv/CABEIAKAAoAMAIgABEQECEQH/xAAbAAADAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAADBAUCAQAGB//EABUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB/8QAFQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH/2gAMAwAAARECEQAAAfiw7yeL3Br2dHG1Tm9ZGdwXYBxV08gMYQetA8GyZyYJvOemi5ZOGJ4FjRxcVnRL7RRJxy5BF1gB4ozIN4Pb8yFpkoADMGAt+6cAYRPh2YZzB+ifCiOq84FC0uULUi8EIMxvfOmiDIeXKoT476grrORgOCCw9jLqL4BS/M2XNKHKHvniH0G47A0LBCBJ+2mnzO+cNlUpkvF2QWhNAJ7W+D7XCCk2ogPmlaKRpjpwVXJ8ojdTO/RpUjHzd2EEwlwrtr2hxN9QXVdGJUOunOnCLLmAQGHxjLIjCvyVCYOz7KIf6D5KwfQ9RcAt9GNbDwIvwJwfRgwGVHlDKGB1Kp8vwJSdSA2UnYxCzyf0f4DZwehHR+GYB5gLOozihfkWT83p6dGU6OBQstwb9woIuBBRjCGWGwdc9oEi6sUHt0Jf/8QAJhAAAgIBBAICAgMBAAAAAAAAAQIAAxEEEBIhEzEiMiBBBRQjQv/aAAgBAAABBQI9b9iZmYD2BOoHhOZwYzxGJWAeY5F+zPW7bZ6yZ7mJiKIVmNvLgc2MB41ct+MM/R/HEA7xiZ2OZgmIktPWJw+IEXsfth2/4CKsAhE4mLSxg0jT+vPHwhHI4AnLb9noExjncRUiUdLSs8CxdMggRRsRLvoVmIwi+z09hE9w9GAZiVkmqnEAgAgmdjtefhznuETx/Kz2diOpphmKgEGw3EMaWdl0gYiB4H7b5QjYr1iabqDsCD8TLY7/ADLfEw+gpJ9Q7GsGPViI5Q12g7BsEYMxOMxGjDI1GncTkYcxe5XMdYySOyWK4GfiJxQzTkk2qYbLUiahoLrINQRPOp3u0qPPq3U9Gqp7I+kXDAqT9MZhT5KVUVsATesZ6zA4BqsBHOchOSiHVplv7FosoCT/AKq03M1VhlsUCa1ACuMfv22B5K9OtcPt1hrmRVHtURV1NsTQCBFSNL/slebMEBRyq7469v8ATkBMloi5ldObWT/Ph0ywrPFzldKLMT1GhmpB8lK4VSITGIVbG8lj5BFhE07ZXTDt/bYhBmDFQ5A2aNswBJlKiWdTVajyRftYNtM8pu684nOppmKdy0Jh2MYxNQAt9jWDQ6RbZfpeFhGY9UTKWVrydBAvKcBgdTMzCZnYwxovQt+v8aYaw67WTT2xGEBnOEzMJ/FjF+TS6fx6/wCiCeQTM8JsZaPG3AqQ7LPK08sB2O5MY5iLgGWe9HhRWRgdyuoxFCjUvwYWBpzE5loRkIcTlMzMLQtEXZofa1ltMlLYpo8YAi1Ey6gMor4lVMG2MbZhaZzESAbGfuoYoT1//8QAFhEAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFg/9oACAECEQE/AaNn/8QAFhEAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFg/9oACAEBEQE/AaNH/8QAKBAAAgEDAwMEAgMAAAAAAAAAAAERAiExECAwEkFhAzJRcUCBIiOR/9oACAEAAAY/AuXJHYe+3BghI8De18F9bbOnY9Z4cF9IG9jjRvffTBZa2Hxy+B8HVrjilfhwPxw+OLqpvtk8aSouf2Nngs2Q2WMaYZek+NfhnS9fB7rn0LSBS7nVn6PbV/h3/a0tUYk9pLhIihOt+Dt6aMtvTqqwZhLsITGnqk1IqkovfYviSMvwWS9NE+pU62RSo0jRENH7FT42I6dtqVt+yWUoikl4Q6vnWSdntZjglq5J0U42Oktkmos+O6ZGKR11fpCrp9r1RJnlZ0jpey/O/rZY6crsZsWL0l1HHVU3Bksfy0pq7c9kncdMWqiS+dXSzp7r8D//xAAlEAEAAgICAwEAAQUBAAAAAAABABEhMVFhEEFxgZEgobHB0eH/2gAIAQAAAT8hUOWU8TBpqDG45jKIauZjeCAGAuO61DVIX5/tOsOYhZpLG41HrmXRLlYfChKGLM7phZZh8h6Srw75zLFheMQ6vSWFxiLb7lLmbY5EGYrebd+DBfghB6MR3GSXPf5LtuMf/IOzn7BfVvEYIm1Rpbubxi7xqU5TQ9cTflL8EHPi6MnMZ1LHX8RLGUwaEz9MSFBjcuR/Juv2LaOGYSzcyFyhqCFf4QfIWzVRuYTf5NizBDQXNxGhPyIVB4IaRheIl0j/AO5SvcQWiVZjVFwhsPC6QQEx8jB3OBATSXfguJ9wz4lC4CX7gqxVTvcSuY6ntpuGUT3KeD5XB8joiuuUPLCaiDnU04Mk8mp4HB5YYYQXKonqEIosTIXEsk5lVMtYRpzCwjqF2+d2yFsLBGHcu9TcRDuU5h2hO0FhjFTSUWRQcrY6d1HIHWp7ekUpAKj0ublnvUXDZeCMb5FFypbjAQvGYj/hMZdLdbSx0xLhKh3Ec0TLeKlOzE0pXJgGDl2JTAMHrEQKYo0X3DintNkjUudP2L5afQlrqzqWbB2RPsfEE3h8gGzsM+AIYW/7TLy+SYYBPWnGMCv8hDgGGC/aS+zzqppFUw4NRaok1MZikEWViYcEz5yTJLTylOBq0If9yy39gcQGiOpoyjd7IYrqWIhbQGElrJuouF6sxksXUXOAmskL8I4uYE2ylBxmadPyHGaeGkAEv0i+yYr+VZuwnLNDMzfuW7tQ2L8cEV15ljqyV1EnhnoNy+G0odzrgARRRhxTJNITYgFm1FyN8vM0EweMFnyGFWG+pc0KfIk/zTZrRLiFQa/oCvhRCGV0XFVH3cs2fq4Vw6uGCImyWB5lhp8iXtB2gEZqhD4jKxeDtqCLqBZpqAJi3w6m8DWzOXEMjiEeyHiL4WL4B+McE0qILFg/YQokpjTmX6bS7eJPb38ghl/IUab6l3vyWXKJaon2ppMhCCBq1lg0xlzqWxyYTK/IR1c7aUw+xGAN0MVaA6mwzNCMssURnE97AmkNmZ/udPypiAVVfoMzIbd9TVW4xTiKncvm+iyfZCyoiGMVyzxPayqPjU03yHCf/9oADAMAAAERAhEAABDCzjyiDggBgAwSRgyyQBASRxhyBiBwwiywwAhAzwjgjBhyxAByyBgAxSAAgihwQQxjjQBThRhDCRAjASAiAiTAADQBiQgggxxywQf/xAAXEQEAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABFg/9oACAECEQE/ENGMKn//xAAXEQADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARFg/9oACAEBEQE/ENHDdP/EACUQAQACAgICAQQDAQAAAAAAAAEAESExQVFhcYGRobHBENHh8P/aAAgBAAABPxD0olnbDzIFw+BDCUrisxmoPhICGhe464i7uWm3WRzKGFcpG6tcCxSifmY0CG7XUtlFyQYItGzdc1/szElqHzDEB2W+yCBWcVM0bIFtallPObhzGos5K4ma9Lupd9jtiKItsZ4hJZr43LtOThGGuLMQrup1MIXri7JUhfbWfUVrVxh94CIBQTANbhWba3Mhe5gUMUXFKi1TX2mKND+Zgkch+YUqlBbJfUVi+CO7vEBesS7A/FyoPYHJFSgnxFtZHYiaAE4IRVNm0MEgQ6hYwDk4xHJw5U5img8RMJFpKcbr5gDSqWBkjDsIAb4K5cQCRjlLRVghjQQdNTDdL5I1Xl0NwHBOaI1lnwIAF8DcAohVpcAW1FodzmgiH7RwYrKPsQOZVGkYHGR+YjmOSHsP7haFKL+cRSSZzfUa/aIIbVVM3C5WHcW8xwLqKJR0OY/AnS6ggNBnLFhBT7/ea51qlMuCseoi6A8EI5m0CLB4G4629h6dSvjldaI+TdAA81KHOWv6lQLK2kRDGcE8STmak1CItYRRR3r4l0R9I1GCth7bgCpifYjwq4hiV+0C4bSh4iUKsyi/MHJZp/EMBtGYi3Ay2LkCxc+0RzlRBRaqbMGkyogD2QKDLADEvVcQ6PxM2Ys+9xdy9z7j2FDlPHH5l5r4RJkmkZtDKxhoX3YDFty+sBKbyXvcw+Q4hclHEaMQcMAtIEQ1DIdsDtNahxXRFvJUcd6T9yxvLz9RgAqMJ1cFI3gWkiGEFVSEAXRnBqAg0chElCVHdEK1Hs2DuMGQ+IVbAa6gCeEEhVLTSXOIS7BEgT1nK1KkDJAzUoahKSMBaS9tSiHL+kNAorLFVD4M/MVtuypWxfqPCxYtdfSpaKLx+8xKNr1Uy4KHkV9ZYAgRrNQybJWiYAqOb3HkhRwQhUubyJRMQbpzC4nu1AFh9ZyC5btchc+YAPYNKR2ghAxCjA23cJyrxVccOHkq/UobKqhmACcDUR6n7SkgqwYYHRLsIV17l7XqALV/4ma8erPwsIwUwCr7So8Vl2xSW7Aw24epnUHauUaHRRKGVzQE9120+suY6t4Zl2W3HZX9wrBt4leeITkwaYQBp/xBY6GiEhSR+JTFAw7RL2hxcAzhpTBcNFiy/wDrmmAKuKcavGXxClUrVua4v3AdDtCo40XcpbEjtVkpp/dRlJBLV8lr7hUc8Oa+ZUD+aYHxKwNwAlEu9zLBkPVw+7F0epXnC0BwT0gZJDKQCl9zbR+YX/JzgsoKMaXcsaZ0lxB2LvRDU1nJO5Tc4BZd0yhshBQ+JauAK1zxXzKx7FtKzCIoMV3HaF9wYrIARjkwD4gTVjI0EACKmin4I0SqpyR8k0ejgioKVpdwW/KwQuMIV9CKy7ZOkFLdGxjSyZw4l2kL6zDiwkV8G4/yZgZU64P8BBuhqUKgHARYBZheIFghMQg0t26PEY8G5esRKWNrmriq5hHYg9zu2Ze6L0QO52kIHmXPqCP3EqljxWzAsefM3eszACnKH6TGyNmv6CBrbMrFncxjLkfS9SpMtMVhDRjD3lVqriOAeZSOVRyAOOIV+jKOZUYZc2vMZGpm/gVbZgHLBA8S8eGODQlvz5lhhAYhN0uXOGUx6Gz/ACXKx9wgtwOmBdfmA6mCMlRcZlBMUoNxR6gYeiO/MwlYAXLwZtfmNoWoYJicqTnpMTRANPP6hsAjHNMfqleTSXO13GxFixDsGHcfbEBnL3MkcoVmyJk1dSqKy2zGRW8wDVCiD6wOh9LDdvULgWaCCnB04j1YW4ZNtiVqHQlWQkGedS1NBVCj6QUcz3PhP4L4PLDG47TMfzfiCGosgnrTOUJ3AS3L3K8oNYfuaDXMIK0svwiqAqcEs9fnmo222RTTFyE8C+oPFtO4KsQbiCNGWOmCcwg5jvFRFICArUrVTRmdo3HGabOp/9k=
--=_data-uri--

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the page in `IE6`, the image doesn't show up. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong, and how to fix it so that it shows up fine in `IE6`? I am saving the file in my desktop and trying to open that in `IE6`...

Update:

As per Musa's comment below, I changed the code to include the hack in the CSS only. Still not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_data-uri"

--_
Content-Location:locoloco
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

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

--=_data-uri--
*/
#pic {
width:670px;height:710px; *background: expression("url(mhtml:" + window.location + "!locoloco)");

}
</style>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() { alert(window.location); }
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p>Foo</p>
    <div id="pic" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you check if this work on other browser? cause it's not working in chrome

Comment: @JanDvorak, please check the resources I have shared, the link you provided is the same as mine. Please go through the question at least before voting to close...

Comment: @BkSantiago, I don't think it will work in Chrome. `MHTML` is supposed to work in IE only...

Comment: @JanDvorak, plus if you look at the comments at that page, in particular by Varun, you will find that it is not working for others as well...

Comment: @Cupidvogel sorry; I saw an answer (removed a while later, as I found out after closevoting) referencing that answer as a solution. Please ignore my closevote then

Comment: Why did you separate the hack, put them back together like in the blog post and see if it works.

Comment: Okay then, no problem. If you can think of any solution, please share..

Comment: @Musa, i didn't quite get you. What do you mean **separate the hack**?

Comment: On http://venodesigns.net/2010/06/17/you-got-your-base64-in-my-css/ the hack is in the css comment but you have piece in a html comment and the rest in a div.

Comment: Okay, I am trying that also. Gimme two minutes..

Comment: Hi @Musa, see edit, still not working..:(

Comment: Try doing it in a css file like in the example.

Comment: Did that too. Still no result! :(

Comment: why is it so important to support ie6? that browser is more than a decade old!

Comment: Yeah, we had discussion with other colleagues, we are not going to support it. Thank God!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong resources separator in your code:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_data-uri"
```

Here `=_data-uri` is a delimiter you have to use to separate images from each other.

E. g.:

```
/*
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_"

--_
Content-Location:locoloco
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

iV... // image here
--_
Content-Location:locoloco2
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

iV... // image here
*/
```

You don't need separator at the end of the last image.

In your code you have declared separator `=_data-uri`, use separator `_` before first image and used `=_data-uri--` after it.

To make it work, change first one to the declared one and remove the one in the end.

This code worked for me (also wrote fixed url in mhtml, be sure to change it to the right one for you):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_"

--_
Content-Location:locoloco
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

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
*/

#pic {
    width:670px;
    height:710px;
    *background: expression("url(mhtml:http://localhost/~iadramelk/tmp/base64.html!locoloco)");

}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<p>Foo</p>
<div id="pic" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

base64 images are showing up in IE6 and IE7... in the last i found a simple solution when you are using a encoded images in css.

**"write two different property in a same class"**

I am going to explain it below.

```
<div class="myClass">    </div>
<style>
    .myClass {
            /*this will work for other browsers*/
            background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAHCAYAAADam2dgAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAAySURBVHjaYlSdd/4/AwQwQml0PgMTHsn/yIoYCCmEKcKrEFkRTrcxEVIAs46g7wACDACraA+g90OOjwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D');        
            /* For ie6 and ie7*/
            *background:url('give real path_to_image');
    }
</style>
```